# Opt out of moderation process for Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Is there a way to opt out of the moderation process to add a place to the Google Maps database?

Basically, I'd like to build an app for finding technicians near a certain area, but I would like to populate the places with an internal database of locations of third party certified technicians.  These locations are only pertinent to users of the app, so it would make no sense to be able to search them in any Google Maps search.

I'd like only my app to be able to see these locations.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) in adding these places/locations, your application can search this location immediately by using Nearby Searches.

Even though your location that you add is not accepted by the moderation process, you will still able to see this in your application.

But if you want to pass the moderation process, your add request should include as much information as possible. In particular, the following fields are most likely to improve the chances of passing the moderation process: **phone number**, **address** and **website**.

For more information, check this whole [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place#add-place-overview).

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).